# Flat faces don't subdivide properly

Tags: modeling, mesh, export, faces

Blender 2.81.16

I have to do a mold and I have several flat faces, and I need to reduce the face counts, also because I will use the obj file in other programs.
I got to this point after working in the flat faces:
Select area> X (remove faces) > select contour > Fill > Select Face (1) (first picture)

When I select Face (big) and Subdivide it makes a subdivision of a face in several small corners, not big divisions.

I think I'm doing something wrong because when I Export as .OBJ to another software, these big faces are not recognized (a hole appears in the object), (for example meshmixer). Do you know why? How it could be solved?

[image]
[image]

To decide the Subdivision point I think I could solve the problem selecting 2 vertex and Fill, but I still have the problem of "ghost faces".

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53130/subdivide-a-face-into-smaller-faces/53134#53134 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52785/how-do-i-fill-an-area-with-faces-lined-up-in-a-grid-over-a-not-flat-surface/52810#52810 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/what-is-the-technical-difference-between-an-ngon-and-a-bunch-of-triangles/1697#1697

Comment: thank you for your answers. And do you know why they desappear in meshmixer for example, or simply stops in some CAD programs?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they/95#95