# How to convert straight edges to curved edges in blender?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges

[image]

I am  blender beginners,
but I am experiencing this problem.
I need to build a cap model. I don't know how to build a curved edge

Comment: You can't create a properly curved edge between two vertices, but you can simulate it with the Subdivision Surface modifier, then keep some angles straight and square with additional edge loops. To make your cap, first you need to build a rather basic and squared shape of this object with extrusions, then add a Subdivision Surface that will artificially add some roundness, and click on the Smooth button on the T menu to make it look smooth. Check out some tutorials about basic modeling and Subdivision Surface.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81340/curved-mesh-topology-2