# Ngons and messy Topology on flat Surfaces

Tags: topology, subdivision-surface

I am creating a model of my car which I hope to release on turbosquid.

I have used neat topology for the majority of my model, however I have no way of creating the car radio the way I want to without some ngons and messy topology.

Will this affect the final render and if so is there any way to go about it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Quads and n-gons are converted to triangles during the render process, which might lead to unpredictable outcomes that generate shading errors, epecially in non-flat areas. So, the best thing would be to render just that part (maybe from different angles, to be sure)  and then decide if the outcome is good enough.

Comment: If the mesh is going to stay flat and not be deformed then you might be able to get away with it. If you have some shading issues then try putting loop cuts around the ngons to protect the rest of the mesh.

Comment: Looks like the kind of thing that should be modeled as separate objects or at least separate mesh chunks. It will significantly reduce poly count, unecessary loops and considerably ease you life. Buttons don't need to be physically connected to the panel, in fact in real life they are not

Comment: Look at https://topologyguides.com/ , there are several pages of sound advise there. Pay attention on techniques to create poles and loop reduction flows, so that you can have detail where you need it, and have less vertices in flat areas where you don't need as many. Do avoid n-gons if you can, even just to get used to having clean topology at all times. You have a lot of unnecessary vertices.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Topology Guides Guides for 3d Artists](https://topologyguides.com/) first you should learn the basics to have a clean topology and not the clutter that is seen in your model, so you will achieve a good quality render and you will make your work easier by reducing the render time
2. You can use **`Loop Tools`** Addon, it is in user preferences addons, activate it and it will appear in ***edit mode*** when you ***press*** **`W`**
3. Example to create a good[image: Topology] [image: Topology]
4. Apply Smooth in Object Mode [image: Smooth]
5. and maybe you can apply a subdivision surface modifier [image: SubDivide Modifier] [image: Control panel]
6. You can also read many very good answers that are here, and do not wait for the magic addon to arrive, which may never arrive

   [Topology](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28427/58715)

   [more Topology](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32040/58715)
7. [image: Panoramic pic] [image: Panoramic]
8. when finished remember to apply scale and rotation, so that when you do not have scaling problems, remember to adjust the normals of your model

   8.1 Object Mode

   8.2 `CTRL` + **A**, Scale and Rotation

   8.3 Edit Mode

   8.4 select all and apply `CRTL` + **N**