# Why does cloth sewing not work correctly on this imported SVG?

Tags: cloth-simulation, svg

I drew a body pattern for clothing simulation using Inkscape.
Then I imported the pattern to Blender with .svg extension file.

I filled the curve (when I import the pattern, it was curve type not mesh) in 2D for both and then I converted it to the mesh.

When I switch the mode to edit mode, there are a lot of points that I did not create, and a lot of lines (I think these lines are grid line but I do not understand why and how it created).

The pattern I filled in 2d for both and converted to the mesh:

[image]

The pattern in edit mode. As you can see, there are a lot of points and lines while I created only red points that I marked:

[image]

Since there are only horizontal lines, when I sew the pattern with the function in Blender, the cloth only folds in up&down direction like the images below

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I want to wrap this cloth on the body model like pictures below. I took them from Youtube video:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think the difference is that, this pattern has vertical lines as well, so when the cloth is sewing, it wrap in left-right direction as well.

[image]

Therefore, I want to have that vertical lines on my patterns.
How can I add those lines with python script?
Or, do I have to add them manually?

Comment: IMO The last picture says it all. If you imagine the  edges like a wire fence, think of the effect of pulling on different vertices.  Also make and see how this flows and curves nicely with subdivision surface.  Would lose the inkscape step, and put in the "red dot" coordinates directly into blender (via script and coords if need be get out he graph paper).  If its L-R symmetrical use a mirror modifier as shown too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main concept to learn is that faces do not bend unless they are subdivided.

The first image shows that the object has no vertical subdivisions. How do you expect to bend it?

Rambling answer:

SVGs are converted to curves when imported to blender. When you convert curves (or text) to mesh the resulting geometry is usually triangulated or quite irregular, useless for the most part.

A workaround is not to fill the shape and fill it yourself. To do that, just import the SVG but before converting to mesh, set the fill on the curve to None, so that you only keep the outline.

Proceed to convert curve to mesh and you will be left with some vertices connected with edges outlining the object.

In Edit Mode select those edges and do "Grid Fill" and play with the settings for grid fill until you get an evenly divided mesh comprised of quad faces.

The resulting object should bend the way you need it to.

Here is an example borrowed from a [different answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28428/92768):

[image]

Note that for grid fill to work you need an **Even** number of vertices on the outline.

Also, in the shape you show on the question, you will need more subdivisions at the bottom, on the straight line.