# Decrease the number of vertices on the mesh boundary

Tags: mesh, cloth-simulation

I have a mesh converted from filled curve.
Left image is filled curve, and the right is a mesh converted from left in edit mode

[image] [image]

As you see the right image arm part, there are a lot of vertices.

[image]

Since there are a lot of vertices only those area, when i sew this pattern with cloth function, it has unbalance problem.
What I want to do is that,
Optimally, it would be the best if the shape stays the same but the number of vertices is decreased.
However, it would be also okay, even the shape changes though, I want to reduce vertices on the curve areas which are arm and neck part.

And as you can see, there are no vertical line but all horizontal lines. this is also the problem.

If, I can create horizontal lines on that area, it could be alternative solution instead of reducing the vertices.

How can I do?

Thank you very much:)

Comment: This issue is the choice of a filled imported SVG curve. A filled curve, as with a font is going to give you a mess. Either as commented to a prior question create a minimal grid with good topo and subsurf (as shown in image in a prior post)  Or remove the faces and grid fill.   Consider adding a link to SVG, or a blend to question.

Comment: @batFINGER Thank you very much for your kind answer :) Unfortunately, I did not fully get it, would you explain more in detail please?

Comment: please share your file so that we can find the best way to simplify it: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Commented here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184984/why-does-cloth-sewing-not-work-correctly-on-this-imported-svg/185007#comment309961_184984 Well explained in answer  here too   https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/185007/15543 decimate or unsubdivide after grid fill.

Comment: Since you keep asking for help with the exact same issue you asked before, I would like to know what in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184984/why-does-cloth-sewing-not-work-correctly-on-this-imported-svg) did not work for you? The answer is the same, or if it isn't please let us know why.

Comment: @susu No, it was not the same question, before that, I need to create edges between many vertexes, since there are a lot of vertexes. But now, I solved that problem with "Bridge Edge Loops", "Shift+Alt+Mouse left" and delete only face. And this problem is that there are too many vertexes near arm hole area, so I needed to reduce the number of vertexes. However, as I reduce the resolution of render, I solved this problem. Thank you very much for your help :)