# How can I split a large face into nice even triangles?

Tags: mesh, faces

I have a simple 2D shape outline imported from a .svg file and converted to a mesh.

[image]

This shape has been populated with loads of very elongated triangles, which are not very practical for future editing. Instead, I would like to populate it with nice evenly-sized and not excessively elongated triangles.

I have been able to remove the existing subdivisions with a limited dissolve:
[image]

I have then tried a couple of options. "Fill" is a slight improvement but still not great:
[image]

The best I have managed is using the "Simplify" brush in Sculpt mode. With Dyntopo selected, constant detail, I do a flood fill and get this:

[image]

This is getting closer to what I am after, but note that the outline has now been distorted. If I apply the brush manually, I can avoid the edges but then only partially solve the problem. I could use a higher level of detail for the "simplify" but then end up with a lot of excess triangles.

I would like a way to produce something like the bottom image, but keeping the outline as unaltered as possible from the original. Is there a simple way to do this? There is probably a simple answer, I am quite new to Blender.

Comment: I don't think you can lock vertices from changing when using dyntopo in that scenario. What you could do is to solidify the plane temporarily and then use Remesh modifier with some option like new Voxel remesh or Sharp to keep original shape, then Triangulate modifier

Comment: Instead of flood filling the surface use **grid fill** https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184984/why-does-cloth-sewing-not-work-correctly-on-this-imported-svg/185007#185007

Answer (score 2):

@susu has a good suggestion in the comments which has worked well for me.

1. Remove the face so that we just have the outline of edges and vertices.
2. Subdivide some of the longer edges so that the vertices are roughly evenly spaced
3. Face -> Grid fill (with all vertices selected)
4. Face -> Triangulate faces

Result:
[image]