# I'm trying to making clothes starting from the pattern sew

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

i'm trying to bring my clothes sketch to life just to get an idea of how would it be in reality.

I'm starting from this reference:
[image]

I started using bezier curves,
[image]

than tried to fill it, but it can't.

I wanted to use garment tools addons, and tried to make the pattern warp around the mannequin.

Since it can't be filled, i't can't be warped. I tried even to convert the bezier into mesh, but it adds too many vertex and its impossible to work with.
[image]

Please, someone could explain/suggest some way to make it easier, (also for making the eye cut) i'm literally losing my mind on this from one day.

Comment: There is a built-in sewing tool in Blender under the Cloth-Physics properties "Shape" section. Did you try that? You can find tutorials on Youtube.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184984/why-does-cloth-sewing-not-work-correctly-on-this-imported-svg