# boolean gone wrong?

Tags: modifiers

I tried to cut a hole in this mesh using boolean, as you can see it worked but the vertices around the edges of the hole are not connected to the main mesh. What can i do to fix this? as i think it might cause a problem when texturing.

[image]

Comment: you edit to edit the mesh manually or use the "loop tool" circle function to make the hole.

Comment: avoid booleans if you can. you will end up with terrible topology. But if you must use boolean make the shape so that is doesn't cross your object completel, but only the front part. For other alternatives read this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28425/curved-mesh-topology

Comment: Avoiding booleans in such situations are the best idea . For now you can use the knife tool and connect the vertices to the rest of the mesh...I would recommend that you watch Josh Gambrell's video on boo and topology.You can also make selected vertecies to a circle by clicking alt+ shift + s

Comment: here is a video on how to make holes:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA and in this page: https://topology-guides.tumblr.com/page/5